# MySQL procedure if clause then a insert into

Tags: mysql

i am making a stored procedure in mySQL

```
if (myImg is null) then
update images
set images.image=myImg
where images.artist=myArtist;
end if;

insert into songs
(name,artist,year,audio_path)
values (myname,myartist,myyear,mypath);
```

when i click the button of "continue" i got an error message: #1064.
the error is at the line 8 (the line of the insert into songs).

any idea?

Comment: `year` is a reserved word in MySQL. Your column names should be escaped with the backtick symbol. Try `insert into songs (\`name\`,\`artist\`,\`year\`,\`audio_path\`) values (myname,myartist,myyear,mypath);`

Comment: i have tried but it do not resolve the error :(

Comment: What is the entire `create procedure` definition? Append to the question, not as another comment.

Comment: Then you'll need to debug that SQL statement, preferably using the same sample values that your stored procedure is using.

Comment: @kmoser ... Know that `year` is not a reserved word. There is no `(R)` designation by the `YEAR` keyword in the [reference list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-Y).

Comment: this few code lines is the entire procedure

Comment: @PaulT. True, not technically a reserved word, but it's still a good idea to surround table and column names with backticks.

Comment: @Euronymous Where are the values coming from and what are they?

Comment: @kmoser i am using phpmyadmin so, i am creating the procedure from there. The values are not on the code. The values are all varchar (255) except year.

Comment: should i create the procedure with pure code